# Streaming results of JDBC query with playframework and ebean

Tags: jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

Is there a way (preferrably with Ebean) to get ResultSet streaming from the server?
(like it is possible with JDBC ResultSet.setFetchSize).

Also, if possible, can the fetch size be adjusted dynamically on the same result list?

I am asking this beacause I am working on an async web service in Play framework 
and I would like to return (or stream) results to the clients as soon as possible
like I understand that is possible with node.js.

I would like to use Postgresql as the database.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `defaultFetchSize=-2147483648` to your mysql connection like:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.1/DBNAME?defaultFetchSize=-2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Asynchronous processing of the request, in which you return the answer in several fragments. There is documentation about it for both [Play 1.x](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous#HTTPresponsestreaming) and [Play 2.0](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaStream).

I may be wrong, but I believe it's not possible to stream directly from the request to the database, what you do is to create an asynchronous request to the database and, once you get the rows you wanted, you iterate the results and return the answer to the client. See the examples linked above.